# mysql Replication stalled

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am having mysql 8.0 installation with replication between 2 servers in master-master configuration. While  data is being replicated from server A to server B the replication is stalled from hours. Below is the snippet for `show slave status \G` on server B.

```
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
           Master_SSL_Key:
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 49808
            Last_IO_Errno: 0
            Last_IO_Error:
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error:Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
         Master_Server_Id: 1
         Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                SQL_Delay: 0
      SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
  Slave_SQL_Running_State: waiting for handler commit
       Master_Retry_Count: 86400
              Master_Bind:
  Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
 Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
           Master_SSL_Crl:
```

After executing `show processlist;` i am getting a process that is waiting from a long time , having a wait time of 50071 and increasing

```
 system user     |                               | NULL | Query       | 50071 | waiting for handler commit
```

What steps shall i take to bring my replication on track?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. Adding:

```
   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

Solved the problem for me on MySQL 8.0.13 installation.
Read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

And see also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232365/mysql-8-0-updates-are-sometimes-stalling